# spring boot values not substituted by gradle during Integration test

Tags: spring, gradle, spring-boot, spring-test, spring-test-mvc

I don't know if this is a spring boot or gradle issue

I am using spring boot 1.4 to build Restful Services.
I have a StatusController class which gives status of service. This includes service name,buildtime,environmenet and version.

Here is my Controller

```
@RestController
public class StatusController
{

    @Value("${service.version: not configured}")
    private String version;

    @Value("${service.name: not configured}")
    private String appName;

    @Value("${service.env: not configured}")
    private String env;

    @Value("${service.timestamp: not configured}")
    private String buildDate;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/status", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    @ResponseBody
    public String getStatus() throws JsonProcessingException {
        Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("version", version);
        map.put("appName", appName);
        map.put("env", env);
        map.put("buildDate", buildDate);
        return new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(map);

    }
}
```

**src/main/resources/application.properties**

```
service.name=${name}
service.version=${version}
service.timestamp=${timestamp}
```

**build.gradle** (only relevant section)

```
processResources {
    expand project.properties
}

def buildTime() {
    def today = new Date()
    def formattedDate = today.format('MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss z')
    return formattedDate
}

ext.timestamp=buildTime()
```

I have version defined in **gradle.properties**

```
version=1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.
```

when I start my service (gradlew bootRun) and I hit /status, I see all the values injected (not the default values of "not configured". However, in my tests, see the values not being substituted but default values injected.

Here is my test class

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment= SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class ApplicationTests {
    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
        System.out.println("test passed");
    }

    @Value("${service.version: not configured}")
    private String version;

    @Value("${service.name: not configured}")
    private String appName;

    @Value("${service.env: not configured}")
    private String env;

    @Value("${service.timestamp: not configured}")
    private String buildDate;

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Test
    public void exampleTest() throws Exception {
        String lifeCheck = this.restTemplate.getForObject("/status", String.class);
        System.out.print(lifeCheck);
    }
}
```

using debugger, I confirmed the values are not substituted in the test class.
but also not substituted in controller

Here is the output from running above test

```
{"appName":" not configured","buildDate":" not configured","env":" not configured","version":" not configured"}
```

Comment: Where and how are you running your tests? Via Gradle from the command line? Within an IDE without using the IDE's testing support?

Comment: If you are running the tests in the IDE, the following Gradle forum discussion may prove useful to you: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/gradle-eclipse-seems-to-ignore-any-user-defined-logic-in-processresources-and-processtestresources-tasks/7358/9

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that there's a separate task in Gradle called `processTestResources`

Comment: why would that matter? I am replacing the placeholder in src/main/resources/application.properties which should happen in `ProcessResources`

Comment: Yes but tests use `src/test/resources/application.properties` and you're not expanding the placeholders in the proper task, e.g. `processTestResources`

Answer (score 0):

Place the application.properties in your **src/test/resources/**

The test classes cannot see your main resources. The values will be substituted if you place it in your test resources folder. :)

Comment: I am injecting values. order of injection will be src/main/resources/application.properties followed by src/test/resources/application.properties. Anyway, it did not work placing in test resource folder

Comment: I just want to point out that spring boot tests can pick up `application.properties` files in `src/main/resources`.  This answer is not correct.